# Next.js how to use tRPC with a server components correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, trpc, t3

I am learning T3 stack with App router. But I ran into a problem with using tRPC.
90% tutorial in the Internet shows how to combine tRPC with next js using hooks, for example:

```js
const {data: posts, isLoading} = api.posts.all.useQuery({});
```

But it's a hook! It can be rendered only in a client component. So it kills SSR, SSG, whatever.
IDK why everybody on youtube shows this way to get data. I have watched a video like this on the official `Theo T3` YT channel.

So, how to correctly get data in server components using tRPC with next.js?

I found 2 ways, but I haven't fully figured them out.

- **Way 1** - using `createTRPCProxyClient` that T3 CLI provides. I create tRPC `serverApi`, then in a server component I load data and pass it as props to CLIENT component that use tRPC hook useQuery with initialData. It works, okay, but it's so complex, isn't it? Moreover, it requires `noStore()` call before every `serverAPI` - it's so confusing! Witout `noStore()` dev server works absolutely fine, but when I run `npm run build` I get an error.
  P.S. sorry for a lot of code

```js
// trpc/server.ts
import "server-only";

import {
  createTRPCProxyClient,
  loggerLink,
  TRPCClientError,
} from "@trpc/client";
import { callProcedure } from "@trpc/server";
import { observable } from "@trpc/server/observable";
import { type TRPCErrorResponse } from "@trpc/server/rpc";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { cache } from "react";

import { appRouter, type AppRouter } from "@/server/api/root";
import { createTRPCContext } from "@/server/api/trpc";
import { transformer } from "./shared";

/**
 * This wraps the `createTRPCContext` helper and provides the required context for the tRPC API when
 * handling a tRPC call from a React Server Component.
 */
const createContext = cache(() => {
  const heads = new Headers(headers());
  heads.set("x-trpc-source", "rsc");

  return createTRPCContext({
    headers: heads,
  });
});

export const serverApi = createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({
  transformer,
  links: [
    /**
     * Custom RSC link that lets us invoke procedures without using http requests. Since Server
     * Components always run on the server, we can just call the procedure as a function.
     */
    () =>
      ({ op }) =>
        observable((observer) => {
          createContext()
            .then((ctx) => {
              return callProcedure({
                procedures: appRouter._def.procedures,
                path: op.path,
                rawInput: op.input,
                ctx,
                type: op.type,
              });
            })
            .then((data) => {
              observer.next({ result: { data } });
              observer.complete();
            })
            .catch((cause: TRPCErrorResponse) => {
              observer.error(TRPCClientError.from(cause));
            });
        }),
  ],

});

// app/page.tsx
// ...
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from "next/cache";
import { serverApi } from "@/trpc/server";

const ResentTweetsPage: NextPage = async ({}) => {
    noStore();
    // ^^^^^^^^ How to remove it?

    const tweets = await serverApi.tweet.infiniteFeed.query(
        {},
    );


    return (
        <TabsWrapper
            current="Recent"
        >
            <RecentTweets
                initialTweets={tweets}
            />
        </TabsWrapper>
    );
};

export default ResentTweetsPage

// components/RecentTweets
'use client';

import { api } from "@/trpc/react";
import { serverApi } from "@/trpc/server";

export const RecentTweets: FC<{
    initialTweets: Awaited<ReturnType<(typeof serverApi.tweet.infiniteFeed.query)>>
}> = ({
    initialTweets
}) => {
    const tweets = api.tweet.infiniteFeed.useInfiniteQuery(
        {},
        {
            getNextPageParam: lastPage => lastPage.nextCursor,
            // Thanks for it the page render this data at first loading
            initialData: {
                pageParams: [],
                pages: [
                    initialTweets
                ]
            },
            refetchOnMount: false,
            refetchOnReconnect: false,
            refetchInterval: 1000 * 60
        }
    );

    return (
        <InfiniteTweetList
            tweets={
                tweets.data?.pages.flatMap(page => page.tweets)
            }
            isError={tweets.isError}
            isLoading={tweets.isLoading}
            hasMore={Boolean(tweets.hasNextPage)}
            fetchNewTweets={tweets.fetchNextPage}
        />
    );
};
```

- **Way 2** - using `createCaller`. I still need to pass `initialTweets` to client component, and there's no `.query()` in `await serverClient.tweet.infiniteFeed({})`. I would prefer this method, but when I run `npm run build`, I get this error: `Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used 'headers'` and I haven't found how to fix that.

```js
// trpc/serverClient.ts
import { appRouter } from "@/server/api/root";
import { httpBatchLink } from "@trpc/client";
import { createTRPCContext } from "@/server/api/trpc";

export const serverClient = appRouter.createCaller(
    await createTRPCContext({} as any)
)

// app/page.tsx
import {NextPage} from 'next';
import React from "react";
import { RecentTweets } from "@/components/RecentTweets";
import { serverClient } from "@/trpc/serverClient";
import { TabsWrapper } from "@/app/feed/components/TabsWrapper";

const ResentTweetsPage: NextPage = async ({}) => {
    const tweets = await serverClient.tweet.infiniteFeed(
        {}
    );


    return (
        <TabsWrapper
            current="Recent"
        >
            <RecentTweets
                initialTweets={tweets}
            />
        </TabsWrapper>
    );
};

export default ResentTweetsPage
```

Thanks you for your help